# Prove that two kernels are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional linear space.
How do you prove that there exists such an m that:

$$\text{ker} (T^m) = \text{ker} (T^{m+1}).$$

I have managed to prove using induction that for each $m≥1$, 
$\text{ker} (T^m) ⊆ ker (T^{m+1})$.
So, I have a unidirectional inclusion.
Instead of proving the inclusion in the other direction I think I can just prove that the dimensions of the two sets are equal.
I understand that

$$\text{Dim} V = \text{Dim ker}T + \text{Dim ImT},$$

but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: can you really use induction here because you are supposed to prove the existence of such m not for all m

Comment: what I have proven with induction for each m is the one directional inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $V_m=\text{ker}(T^m )$

Each time $V_m\subsetneq V_{m+1}$ then the dimension of the subspace $V_m$ increases by at least $1$.

On the other hand $|V_m|\leq |V|$ for all $m$. Therefore, $V_m$ is a strict subspace of $V_{m+1}$ finitely many times.

So, there is an $m_0$ such that for all $n\geq m_0$, we have $V_n=V_{n+1}$.

Comment: why is the dimension of Vm increase by at least one each time.and why do we end up reaching an m0 where the equality happens?

Comment: @eventhorizon02 if $V \subset W$, where $V$ and $W$ are linear spaces then $|V| = |W|$ implies $V=W$. So the dimension must increase to have strict inequality. Now, $|V_m|\leq |V|$, however if $|V_m|$ increases more than $|V|$ times more than $1$ then $|V_m|$ would exceed the number $|V|$ obtaining a contradiction

Comment: it makes sense intuitively, I just need to figure out the formal description of it

Comment: @eventhorizon02 For both of these statements?

Comment: the part where I have to show that for each increase in m.... just need to figure out how to write it out mathematically

Comment: @eventhorizon02 Suppose that $m_1<m_2<m_3$ are times of an increase then. Then for $m_j$ $|V_{m_j+1}   | - |V_{m_j}|\geq 1$. Since, $m_{j+1}\geq m_j+1$ 
 we get $|V_{m_{j+1}}| \geq  |V_{m_j+1} |$. Therefore,  $|V_{m_{j+1}}   | - |V_{m_j}|\geq 1$. Summing over $j$ and noticing that this is a telescopic sum we get $|V_{m_{n+1}}   | - |V_{m_1}|\geq n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{\dim\ker(T^k):k\ge0\}$; this set of natural numbers is bounded by $\dim V$, hence there is an $m$ so that $\dim\ker(T^m)$ is maximal.

Now you know that $\ker(T^{m})\subseteq\ker(T^{m+1})$, which implies
$$
\dim\ker(T^{m})\le\dim\ker(T^{m+1})
$$
By maximality of $\dim\ker(T^{m})$, you infer the two dimensions are equal.

You can also refine the result: if you take the *minimum* $m$ such that $\dim\ker(T^{m})$ is maximal, you have
$$
\{0\}=\ker(T^0)\subsetneq
\ker(T)\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq
\ker(T^{m-1})\subsetneq
\ker(T^{m})=\ker(T^{m+1})=\ker(T^{m+2})=\dotsb
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove by contradiction. Suppose that for all natural number $m$, we have 
$${ker} (T^m) \ne ker (T^{m+1})$$ which implies that $${ker} (T^m)  \subsetneq ker (T^{m+1})$$ since we already have $${ker} (T^m) \subset ker (T^{m+1})$$Therefore, $$Dim \space ker(T^{m+1}) \ge Dim \space ker(T^{m})+1$$ And since $Dim \space ker(T) \ge 0$, we have $Dim \space ker(T^{m+1}) \ge m$, which contradicts the fact that $V$ is finitely dimensional.